# css positioning text after slider wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

I need some help with positioning my css elements in a wordpress theme.  Here is my situation.

First, I call my header.  Inside my header is my horizontal nav menu.

Next, I call my slider from the index.php.  The slider is created in such a way as it takes up 100% of my screen width with 0 margin-top.  Doing this allows my menu to be within my slider images.

My problem is that the next element I call is place directly under my menu, but I would like it placed under my slider images.  How do I do this?  Do I have to give my next element a margin-top equal to the height of my slider images?  Seems there is probably a better way to do this.

The slider is only used on the index page, not on any of the sub pages.

I'm thinking maybe the right answer has something to do with the position tag but I'm not having any luck getting the functionality to work.

Here is the css for my slider positioning.

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1500;
}
```

Here is my index.php file

```
<?php get_header();?>

    <section>
        <?php get_template_part('slider', 'index');?>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="row">
            test
        </div>
    </section>

<?php get_sidebar();?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Here is my header

```
<body>
    <header>

        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name"><h1><a href="<?php echo get_option ('home');?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></h1></li><li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'main-menu' => 'Main Menu', 'container' => false, 'walker' => new Top_Bar_Walker(), 'menu_class' => 'right'));?>
                </section>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </section>

    </header>
```

And here is my slider-index.php file

```
<div class="row full-width slider">
        <div class="preloader"></div>
        <ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit data-options="timer_speed: 6000; slide_number: false; pause_on_hover: false; animation:fade;">
            <?php
            $args = array('category_name' => 'Featured');
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            ?>
                <li><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured');?>
                <div id="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'caption', true);?>" class="orbit-caption"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
                </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>

        </ul>

        <div class="row shadow"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/bottom-shadow.png"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: >Hi Tom, I would like have a look on your html code. Most probably you are missing a **clear div** and you are not placing you **absoulte slider div in a relative div**. Please share you html code if possible so that i can correct you missing code. >Thanks,

Comment: I added it in to my original post.  Thank you.

Comment: I think what has messed me up is using the position tag absolute when I should be using relative.

Comment: If you are using absolute positioning then give your div a fixed height else in case of relative positioning place a clear div ex.

    /*css*/
    .clear{clear:both; height:1px;}
    
    /*html*/
    <div class="clear"></div>

after your section containing the slider. If the pictures used in your slider are of same height then fixed height for the slider container will work in this case.

Comment: Thank you Rahul.  I learned that using relative positioning instead of fixed will allow the next element to load to be in the proper place below.